# custom cell and UITableViewController suggestion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a custom cell for my UITableView. I have put a swipe left right/left observer on my cell. In which that if a user swipes on a cell it will call a function. This function basically creates a UIView that needs to be added to the cell.

I would like my code to use a MVC best practice. So I think what is the appropriate thing to do is to pass in the UIView to the custom cell and let my implementation of my custom cell add it to the cell. In my custom cell I have a property of UIView as well.

The issue is that I will need to adjust the height of the cell as well. Now the method that I have is:

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item {

}
```

this is similar to what a regular heightForRowAtIndexPath, instead of index path it's object. In this method I need to determine whether there is a UIView that needs to be added or not. If there is, the height needs to be adjusted based on that. I can't seem to get my head around this. In this method I can't do self.optionsView, or access any of the property in my custom cell subclass. So how do I check whether the options is added or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rowHight property to your custom cell class, and add another height var to your table view datasource data.
Every time you change the custom cell, make sure to set the height property, and assign it to your data source data in the right position.

Then, inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` just ask for the height data.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

As Idan pointed out it's good to just ask cell for it's content size. I would just use the standard `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
//Assuming myCustomCell contains a placeholder for my additional view called innerView.  
//If the place holder is nil I don't need to adjust cells height.
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Get the cellPath and myCustomCell at this path
    NSIndexPath *rowPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    MyCustomTableCell *myCustomCell = (MyCustomTableCell*)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:rowPath];

    if(myCustomCell.innerView != nil)
        return myCustomCell.innerView.frame.size.height + someDefaultCellHeight;

    else
        return defaultCellHeight;
}
```

Comment: this won't work as I use rowHeightForObject, there's no indexPath here

Comment: Then can't you add that data to the object, something like user_info dictionary or the likes ?